# Use both UART(ttyS0 and ttyAMA0) of raspberry pi Zero W

Tags: raspbian

Is it possible to use both the ttyS0 and ttyAMA0 of raspberry pi zero w at the same time? I don't need the Bluetooth functionality.

Answer (score 3):

No.

`/dev/ttyAMA0` uses GPIO 14/15.

`/dev/ttyS0` uses GPIO 14/15.

The Pi Zero only has one usable UART at a time.